# Ignorar campo al realizar la converson a JSON en un servicio REST en JAVA EE

Tags: json, java-ee

Tengo el siguiente código:

```
@Path("alumnos")
public class AlumnosController {

@GET
@Produces("application/json")
public List<Alumno> getAlumnos() {
    List<Alumno> alumnos = new ArrayList<Alumno>();
    alumnos.add(new Alumno("Javier Octavio", 32));
    alumnos.add(new Alumno("Gerardo Anibal", 32));
    return alumnos;
}

class Alumno {
    private String nombre;
    @JsonIgnore
    private int edad;

    /**
     * @param nombre
     * @param edad
     */
    public Alumno(String nombre, int edad) {
        super();
        this.nombre = nombre;
        this.edad = edad;
    }

    /**
     * @return the nombre
     */
    public String getNombre() {
        return nombre;
    }

    /**
     * @param nombre
     *            the nombre to set
     */
    public void setNombre(String nombre) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }

    /**
     * @return the edad
     */
    @JsonIgnore
    public int getEdad() {
        return edad;
    }

    /**
     * @param edad
     *            the edad to set
     */
    public void setEdad(int edad) {
        this.edad = edad;
    }

    /*
     * (non-Javadoc)
     * 
     * @see java.lang.Object#toString()
     */
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Alumno [nombre=" + nombre + ", edad=" + edad + "]";
    }

}

}
```

deseo ignorar el campo edad, he usado la anotacion JsonIgnore pero no funciona cuando accedo a la url /alumnos me devuelve el json con la edad.

Comment: Puedes agregar el codigo que ocupas para mappear los valores y mostrarlos?

Answer (score 0):

Prueba anotando tu clase así:

Ejemplo:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "algun_nombre")
```

De esta manera en el `get` del campo que no deseas ver lo puedes anotar con:

```
@XmlTransient
```

Comment: Gracias por tu aporte, Oscar. Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en Español. Por favor toma el **[recorrido del sitio](http://es.stackoverflow.com/tour)**. Para futuras respuestas, te recomiendo leer [cómo escribo una buena respuesta](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Saludos.